# Android app with continuous logcat monitoring

Tags: android, android-logcat

I am trying to implement the solution for a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8017082/how-to-view-continuous-logcat-in-my-application-in-emulator) that was proposed by user 
[Kevin Galligan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/227313/kevin-galligan). However, I keep getting the error "No enclosing instance of type LolCat is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type LolCat (e.g. `x.new A()` where x is an instance of `LolCat`)" when creating the new instances of LolCat and `LogcatOut` inside my `OnCreate`.

Sorry for creating a new question for this but I don't have the required reputation to add comments to the older post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a reason, why the inner class `LogcatOut` would need access to the enclosing instance. So you could try to make it static:

```
public static abstract class LogcatOut {
...
}
```

and the error should go away.